# Olingo develop with basic jdbc

Tags: olingo

all. I want to know how to develop Olingo with my jdbc (not jpa), for example:

when I get my DB connection, query and get some entities, then I think I need to fill them into Olingo framework(maybe it's the EDMProvider), could anyone give me some detailed advice?

I have found many articles, but still been puzzled.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want to use Olingo only as a OData reader client right ?
If yes, please find there an exemple provided by [Olingo BasicClientSample](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/OlingoV2BasicClientSample.html).

Then, you'll just have to map your SQL Requests to the PreparedStatements.

Hope it will help you,

Kind Regards.

PS : dont forget to close the thread and mark the answer(s) that helped you !

Comment: Hi, I have almost that issue.But for now, I have another problem.If I use Olingo with jpa, I don't directly expose my persistence entity as metadata entity type, so I have to custom my EdmProvider, such as AnnotationEdmProvider, but when I use this provider, the metadata is ok, but I can't use the jpa to query data, so could you give me some advice?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you'r trying to achieve. You said at first that you dont want to use JPA, but that changed now, right ?

Could you please give us a scenario of what you want precisely ?

Also, is it SAP related ?

Comment: Hi, Dragomitch. I have fixed the problem with Olingo JPA.                                     Thank you!